# Como obtener variables del local storage?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt, pinia

Actualmente tengo inconvenientes con un Login usando Nuxtjs 3 y Pinia para manejar el estado. Hasta ahora es capaz de hacer login y redirigir al usuario a la ruta "/", pero tengo un inconveniente con la forma de obtener el token almacenado en el local storage.

El token esta almacenado, pero al momento de tratar de acceder a el siempre viene null, entiendo que esto puede ser por el SSR (Server Side Rendering) de Nuxt.

En dado caso me gustaría saber si alguien puede darme una mejor solución a como yo trato de hacerlo, soy algo nuevo usando Nuxt.

Aca les muestro como trato de hacerlo.

Este es mi Auth store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { NuxtAppOptions } from '@nuxt/types';
import nuxtStorage from 'nuxt-storage';
import authApi from '../api/auth';

export const useUserStore = defineStore('auth', {

    state: () => ({
        user: JSON.parse(nuxtStorage.localStorage.getData('user') || 'null'),
        token: (typeof window !== 'undefined') ? localStorage.getItem('token') : null,
    }),

    getters: {
        isAuthenticated(): boolean {
            let autenticated = false;

            if (this.token != null) {
                autenticated = true;
            }

            return autenticated;
        },
        getUser(): Object | null {
            return this.user;
        },
        getToken(): string | null {
            return this.token;
        }
    },

    actions: {

        setToken(token: string) {
            this.token = token;
            if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            }
        },

        async login(router: NuxtAppOptions['router'], email: string, password: string) {

            let response = await authApi.login(email, password);

            if (response.status === 201) {
                const { token, ...userData } = response.data;
                this.user = userData;
                this.token = token;

                this.setToken(token);

                router.push({ path: "/" });
            } else {
                // handle error, e.g. show message to user
            }
        },

        logout() {
            this.user = null;
            this.token = null;
            if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
            }
        }
    },
})
```

Y este es mi middleware:

```
import { useUserStore } from '../stores'

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    const userStore = useUserStore();
    if (!userStore.isAuthenticated) {
        return navigateTo('/login')
    }
})
```

Comment: Tal vez esto te sirva [Storage Module · Nuxt](https://nuxt.com/modules/storage)

Comment: @René gracias por comentar, lo he utilizado pero hace lo mismo.

Comment: En otra pregunta comentan que no es posible mientras tengas el modo SSR, tendrías que usar cookies. [Nuxt3 and Pinia how to get localstorage items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74682093/nuxt3-and-pinia-how-to-get-localstorage-items)

Comment: Muchas gracias! efectivamente usando el hook useCookie se puede acceder. @René

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asi como me indican si guardo el usuario en las cookies en vez del local storage es posible acceder a esa data.

De esta forma quedo mi useAuthStore:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { NuxtAppOptions } from '@nuxt/types';
import nuxtStorage from 'nuxt-storage';
import authApi from '../api/auth';
import { error } from 'console';


type User = {
    id: string,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    token: string
}

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('auth', () => {

    const user = useCookie<User | null>('user');
    const isLoggedIn = computed(() => !!user.value);

    const login = async (router: NuxtAppOptions['router'], email: string, password: string) => {

        let response = await authApi.login(email, password);

        if (response.status === 201) {
            user.value = response.data as User;
            router.push({ path: "/" });
        }
    };

    const logout = () => {
        user.value = null
    }

    return { user, login, isLoggedIn };
});
```

y de esta forma mi middleware:

```
import { Middleware, Context } from '@nuxt/types';
import { useAuthStore } from '../stores'


export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {

    const authStore = useAuthStore();

    if (!authStore.user)
        return navigateTo('/login')


})
```

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada.